# apt not working, "Unable to fetch some archives"

Tags: apt, updates, 17.04

I was trying to sudo apt install npm but when I tried to, this is what happened:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, try running apt-get update or apt-get --fix-missing.
```

As well as multiple lines that say something like:

```
Err:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 nodejs amd64 4.7.2~dfsg-1ubuntu3
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

When I do sudo apt-get update, it does not work and says that multiple packages cannot be found or that it can not be installed safely.

I have no idea why it does this or how to fix it. I've been digging for hours but nothing seems to work. Any help?

Comment: This seems like expected behavior. Ubuntu 17.04 reached End Of Life on January 13, 2018. Those repositories are now closed. Consider migrating to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: OK thank you, how would I be able to do that? (Sorry, I am VERY unfamiliar with how Linux works).

Comment: In that case, one easy, tested, supported way is to backup your data, then download and clean-install 16.04 (LTS) or 17.10 (non-LTS). Use a calendar: Ubuntu releases every 6 months, and each release is supported for 9 months - that gives you a 3-month-long window to migrate to the next release. Alternately, use LTS, which releases every 2 years and is supported for 5 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of January 13, 2018 Ubuntu 17.04 has reached end of life.

Now you can replace ca.archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com in /etc/apt/sources.list with old-releases.ubuntu.com.

**But be aware: With 17.04 you won't get any further security updates now and you might still be vulnerable to Meltdown!**

The supported upgrade path from Ubuntu 17.04 is via Ubuntu 17.10.
Instructions and caveats for the upgrade may be found at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades